# Trying to run predict

Tags: r, predict

Tried to run the following predict by selecting columns:

Here's the prior code:

```
model <- glm(Automatable1Y0N ~.,family=binomial(link='logit'),data=train)
data <- subset(training.data.raw,select=c(5,6,7,8,10,12,27))
train <- data[1:800,]
test <- data[801:957,]

model <- glm(Automatable1Y0N ~.,family=binomial(link='logit'),data=train)
anova(model, test="Chisq")
```

NO issues on this 2 lines. And when I ran this predict line:

```
fitted.results <- predict(model,newdata=subset(test,select=c(5,6,7,8,10,12)),type='response')
```

but I'm receiving this error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, r, vars, drop = drop) : undefined columns selected
```

Can someone please help? Thanks.

I tried to extract this subset command:

```
newdata <-subset(test,select=c(5,))
```

Here are the results, when I added column 8 that's when error came up:

```
> newdata <-subset(test,select=c(5))
> newdata <-subset(test,select=c(5,6))
> newdata <-subset(test,select=c(5,6,7))
> newdata <-subset(test,select=c(5,6,7,8))
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, r, vars, drop = drop) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Comment: Probably a variable name mismatch between `model` and `newdata`. But without a reproducible example this is hard to confirm.

Comment: Thanks for your edit, but this does help in us reproducing your problem on our system. For example, we do not have the `train` and `test`objects. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I see what's causing that error: the command:

```
data <- subset(training.data.raw,select=c(5,6,7,8,10,12,27))
```

Here you have now 7 columns, from this command:

```
fitted.results <- predict(model,newdata=subset(test,select=c(5,6,7,8,10,12)),type='response')
```

Instead of specifying the original columns, it should now be

```
select=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

because dataset has now 7 columns. Thanks for providing feedback though @Paul